# Hidden overloaded virtual function OSX QT4

Tags: c++, macos, qt

Have problem with QT4 on my mac, when compiling

> In file included from playlistWidget.cpp:16:
>   ./playlistWidget.h:121:16: warning: 'NPlaylistWidget::mimeData' hides
>   overloaded
>         virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
>       QMimeData *mimeData(const QList items) const;
>                  ^ /opt/local/libexec/qt4/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qlistwidget.h:280:24:
>   note: 
>         hidden overloaded virtual function 'QListWidget::mimeData' declared here:
>         type mismatch at 1st parameter ('const QList' vs
>         'const QList')
>       virtual QMimeData *mimeData(const QList items) const;
>                          ^

My code:

```
private:
        QPointer<QDrag> m_itemDrag;
        bool m_fileDrop;
        QList<QUrl> m_mimeDataUrls;
        QStringList mimeTypes() const;
        QMimeData *mimeData(const QList<NPlaylistWidgetItem *> items) const;
        bool dropMimeData(int index, const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action);
    #ifdef Q_WS_MAC
        Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const;
    #endif
    protected:
        void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
        void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
        void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
        void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event);
        void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This seems to be a warning and should not break compilcation in general. Can you check "Treat Warnings as Errors" setting in your macOS project Build Settings? Try "No" if it's "Yes"

Comment: Yes, it's warning, but it's drag and drop function, and don't work after compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function signature is:
    `QMimeData *mimeData(const QList<QListWidgetItem *> items) const`

Your QList is parameterized by NPlaylistWidgetItem * for a signature of:

`QMimeData *mimeData(const QList<NPlaylistWidgetItem *> items) const`

Change the parameter to QListWidgetItem * and should be fine.
Generally recommend compiling using at least -Wall -Wextra -Werror